# No discovery information when use php webservice with C#

Tags: c#, php, web-services

I got some critical problem when I just try to use php web service with C# windows form application..
My Problem is that Normally when I want to add web reference in my local pc and the web service is running in asp.net 
I can add the web reference and work with It but when I try to add a web reference whic is build in php I got thid error....
Add reference button is inactive and...
Show the message....

**The HTML document does not contain Web service discovery information.**
It shows all methods of my php webservice ...
But what can I do now...
Please Help any One...

Comment: http://arma.iblogger.org/chsarp.jpg   Pliase Check this out.....